# Replacing multiple placeholders in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string with 2 placeholders, that I want to replace on runtime based on value calculations. what is the best way to do this. I have used the code below for single placeholder replacement,

```
   String posttData = @"data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                                ['Label', 'Value'],
                                ['Result', {0}]                           
                                ]);
    var options = {
        width: 1200, height: 500, redFrom: 90, redTo: 100, yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90, minorTicks: 5
    };
```

....result calculation

```
var x = posttData.Replace("{0}", result.ToString());
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "test", x, true);
```

How do I do the same for multiple replacements? if I need to add another option,

```
var options = {
                   width: 1200, height: 500, redFrom: 90, redTo: 100, yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90, minorTicks: 5, max: {1}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about the [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)?

```
String str = String.Format(@"Some value {0} and some value {1}", 1, 2);
```

Should yield:

> Some value 1 and some value 2

You can replace `1` and `2` with whatever results you might need.

Answer (score 5):

I a;ways create an extension method for easier usage.

```
 public static class StringExtensions
    {  
        public static string FormatWith(this string source, params object[] args)
        {
            return string.Format(source, args);
        }
}
```

and call

```
"Some value {0} and some value {1}".FormatWith(1,2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = string.Format(postData,data1.ToString(), data2.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use string interpolation:

```
$"Some value {1} and some value {2}"
```

where "1" and "2" can be whatever result/expression you need.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated