# How to replace placeholders using string.Format() with variable args

Tags: c#, string, string.format

I have a text like: `This is my {0} body from {1} configuration file {2}!`

My args are stored in a `List<string>` called `TextArguments`.

Now, if i code: `this.Text = string.Format(this.Text, this.TextArguments.ToArray<string>())` it works fine.

But if I try to use the suggested extension method FormatWith (e.g. `this.Text.FormatWith(this.TextArguments.ToArray<string>()`) the placeholders aren't replaced.

Any idea?

PS: here the suggested extension method: [Replacing multiple placeholders in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098177/replacing-multiple-placeholders-in-a-string/16098326#16098326)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable so you need to re-assign the result:

```
this.Text = this.Text.FormatWith(this.TextArguments.ToArray<string>())
```